# Better option for loading images in website

Tags: javascript, html, animation, video, gif

I'm want to load images of products in a website with an animation of an hexagon grid

[Hex_loading DEMO](http://gfycat.com/DisastrousEarnestIberianemeraldlizard)

I would like to know what is the best way. 
I've read about inserting a gif, but I think image quality wouldn't be good; or video, but I don't know if it's to much for what I want (also I would have to load directly images for mobile devices).
Is there any other tecnology I'm missing out that would be a better fit for what I want?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: how about animated png? a nice library (to make it compatiable across browsers) could be: http://www.squaregoldfish.co.uk/software/animated-png/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to change the loading pattern. But you can wait for the image to be loaded and then play an animation. 
I suggest using a html5 `<canvas>` element to animate the images.

Comment: I don't want to change the loading pattern.
What I want to know is what is the optimal way of loading an image with that animation. If it's better a gif or a video that when finishes playing changes into the full image.

Comment: I would go for the canvas then. Gifs have a big file size and less colors. Videos also have compression and still a big size. The downside of a canvas is that it requires a bit of javascript skills. So if you don't have those and you don't want to learn those I would use a video instead.

Comment: Thank you @Jespertheend I'll investigate canvas